# Is it possible to have a parent element size itself based on a child element min-width?

Tags: css

I have a parent element with some child elements. The child elements have a `min-width` set, but the parent does not. When the browser window is smaller than the `min-width`, the child elements are the correct width, but the parent keeps getting smaller, causing the children to overflow. Is it possible to force the parent to be at least as wide as the children? (without using javascript)

http://jsfiddle.net/Psczr/

(drag divider most of the way to the right and then scroll right in the result window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue in this situation is that you're using a relative width for the parent and a fixed min width for the children.  The solution you're trying to handle is not possible in straight CSS. You should instead use relative widths for all elements or establish a fixed min width for the parent.

Comment: Ahh I was hoping that there was a css only way, since calculating the largest min-width would take some recursion (this is for some company-internal pages with lots of tables that can get really long), and for this its just not worth the little bit of extra work :)

Answer (score 2):

Set the min-width on the parent and on the child inherit ... but the parent of the `td` in your script is not the `div` but the `tr` ... the parent of the `tr` is the `table` ... and the parent of the `table` is the `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Psczr/12/